# CECUI samples compiled successfully but no executables were generated

Tags: c++, user-interface

I downloaded the latest CEGUI stable release (0.7.1 binary for  Microsoft Visual C++ 2008)
and after hours of setting properties, linker configuration and searching headers files on the internet
I finally got the samples to compile. the big surprise now is that I don't find the executables anywhere.

The msvc++ reports says:

========== Build: 11 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Shouldn´t be 11 new executables out there? the only thing that the compiler made was to create
a new OBJ directory which contains a DEBUG_STATIC directory which contains following 
files i.e. Sample_Demo6:

Sample_Demo6.obj
Sample_Demo6_Static_d.exe.embed.manifest
Sample_Demo6_Static_d.exe.embed.manifest.res
vc90.idb
vc90.pdb

Where are the executables?

If anybody happens to know about a C++ GUI library in which you can design fancy GUIs
(like for games), I mean something in which you can make something like rounded
buttons with rollover effects, embed beautiful background grafics, cool and colorful
progressbars and scrollbars, etc. please let me know!

The library should be open source, cross-platform, and also be allowed to be used for
propetary software.

I know about wxWidgets but like they say on the official wxWidgets site:

wxWidgets gives its applications a truly native look and feel because it uses the platform's native API rather than emulating the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

No -- 11 succeeded means that 11 files (probably object files) were created. 2 failed means that building 2 other files failed. Since the executable typically depends on (nearly) everything else, if *anything* fails to build, it's a pretty good guess that the executable will be among them (nearly the only exception is if you're trying to build more than one executable, in which case one can succeed even if something necessary to building another fails).